# exFAT Refusing to mount - The primary GPT table is corrupt

Tags: linux, windows, gpt, corruption, exfat

I am trying to mount a 4TB exFAT HD on my Manjaro Linux 5.9.11 system. It refuses to mount using the default kernel drivers:

```
mount: /home/user/Ark: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Even tried FUSE without luck:

```
FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
```

Then I opened `gparted` and received this scary error:

```
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used
```

On Windows 10, the drive mounts fine without errors. The disk is pretty much brand new, SMART report is fine. Even the Windows Disk Check gives an all clear after a few minutes of thinking, though I doubt it actually checks anything.

Since I can still read the data fine from Windows, I am thinking of moving the data to another drive and reformatting.

Any ideas what could have caused this? Anything I should do in order to avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT Optimized or flash memory. Not 4TiB drives. The standard exFAT implementation is not journaled and only uses a single file allocation table and free space map. 
But exFAT will store larger files than FAT32. But still should not be used for larger partitions as chkdsk may take forever.  If you need compatibility with a Mac use a smaller exFAT partition.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the first mistake was mounting `/dev/sda`, instead of `/dev/sda1` or some other number.
`/dev/sda` is the whole disk, not a partition.

GPT includes redundant copies, so your "scary error" is that one copy is bad and another is OK.  You should run `gparted` (or `gdisk`) again to make sure that the partition table has been fixed.  If not, you may need to force a write.

I suspect the corrupted partition table is a result of trying to "fix" a filesystem on the disk.

In the future, you might try using tools `blkid` or `lsblk` to determine the actual partitions you want to mount.

Comment: The problem is, the partitions are not showing up... `lsblk` only shows `/dev/sda`. I thought that is a bit strange, but I am now using btrfs everywhere which resides directly on whole disk so I figured perhaps exFat does the same.

Comment: I think before I try 'fixing' anything, I will make a backup of all the data from Windows while I still can.

Comment: Well, with Linux, and probably most Unixes, you CAN put any filesystem on the whole disk.  If you've done that, things might be even more confused.  The fact that a partition table is reported by gparted means that there has been a partioning at some point.  But maybe you overwrote that with an exFAT.  Tool `blkid` can tell you what things appear to be.  Tool `wipefs` can erase the magic numbers from a disk or partition, but requires an option to make an changes, so it is safe to test.  I do recommend a backup.

Comment: You might also look to see if Windows thinks it is partitioned.

Comment: The disk was formatted on Windows, so no fancy pantcy linux-single-disk schmancy woodoo going on... I will make the backup and try the wipefs. If that does not work, I will reformat. I am starting to loose all my hope for exfat... Too bad its the only format that 'works' across various OSs :(

Comment: Thanks anyways for the help!

Comment: Well, if this is an external USB disk, it probably came partitioned.  Then you could have reconfigured it with Windows.  I will admit I find it surprising that Windows would fail to put a partition table on it.  That is usually only done for floppies.